# Is it possible to use Azure DevOps REST API to get the latest comments submitted by a particular user?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

When I checked the documentation, it seems that `workItemId` has to be specified but I would like to get any comment made by a specific user recently without knowing the work item:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/get-comments-batch?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/get-comments-batch?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

Is there any workaround for this?